# How can I close a program on solana?

Tags: solana-cli

I am trying to close my program. When I try to close it I get an error that the flag —programs should be —buffers. But it is not a buffer it is a program. How can I close it?

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out

```
solana program close [programAddy] --keypairs 'urkeypairhere'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are just trying to close a single program you should not need the `--programs` tag. As per the Solana docs you should just need to run `solana program close <BADDRESS>.`
Im assuming your program shows up when you run `solana program show --programs` and not when you run
'solana program show --buffers`?